# User types / role - developers

Tags: database-design, user-roles

You have regular users that use your website/services, they can login to mainsite1, then you have developers, that can not login to mainsite1, but can login to developercenter1. Do you:

1) Store every type of users into 1 large USER table then assign different roles?

or

2) Create a completely separate table just for developers, since they are both completely different users using two different sites?

Comment: Why would you ever create a separate table for developers?  They're people, too.  They're not different **types** of things.  Why create a new table for things of the same type?

Comment: Also, please don't use `'` everywhere.  When you're talking about two things, there's no `'` in things.  "regular user's" is wrong.  It should be "regular users".  Feel free to fix your question to remove just about all of the `'`.  The `'` shows ownership in English.

Comment: @S.Lott: Arguments for: It's possible that developers have an entirely different set of properties, and it's possible it is queried way less, takes up significant room, etc, etc. A myriad of reasons, but still not a great approach in general, IMHO.

Comment: @Noon Silk: "an entirely different set of properties"?  Really?  We're not people?  Is that why my boss treats me so badly?  I don't think there are a myriad of reasons; I think this may be a simple "superclass-subclass" design question.  Except -- perhaps -- @K001 has some idea that is not mentioned in the question.  I need additional details in the question to understand the background.

Comment: Hi S. Lott, sorry If i have offended you, that was not the intended purpose - I'm also a developer and im not a thing. But I was just curious what you would do, but I think I got my answer, option 1 would be best, centralise all user's and keep everything in 1 place! (1 table).

Comment: @K001: "offended"?  I have no clue why that word is in your comment.  I'm asking a question.  Why did you propose separate tables?  What possible reason can you give for separate tables?

Comment: S.Lott, I sympathise about the common error of using an apostrophe-S to pluralise but I suspect you're fighting a losing battle. It's an incredibly simply rule with no exceptions - NEVER use an apostrophe to make a plural - yet so many people don't get it.

Comment: @S.Lott: *sigh*, I'm not going to hand-hold a seemingly competent person through a useless series of guesses about the *OPs* environment (not mine); it does surprise me somewhat that you cannot imagine a situation in which one group of people could be differentiated from another, but that's your position and I don't care to change it. Good day, sir.

Comment: @Noon Silk: The point is not **your** understanding.  You have your own private understanding of some myriad of reasons.  The question is @K001's understanding.  Nothing personal, but your understanding doesn't help any of us understand @K001's considerations.  You can feel put out that no one wants your opinion, but -- sadly -- your opinions don't help us understand @K001's reasons for asking the question this way, do they?  Do you know @K001?  You you know something about this question?

Comment: @S.Lott: You're a bizarre character. I like the vigor with which you have decided to assess any comments to this question. Keep up the good work. Amusing. But I will leave you to it now. I hope you resolve this for him, seriously.

Comment: @Noon Silk: It's an interesting question.  I'm hoping to get background from @K001, not opinions from other folks.  Your depth of knowledge in the area doesn't help anyone understand @K001's question, does it?  Or do you have some insight into the question?

Comment: @S.Lott: Hahahahaha. Do I have insight into the question? It's the first thing I posted! We're in a comedy scene right? Who's on first?

Comment: @Noon Silk: So you know precisely what @K001 is talking about?  If so, then please provide this factual insight.  I though you were just guessing or providing some of your personal opinions.  If you know what @K001 is talking about, please share the specifics.  And please provide some justification for how you know these things about @K001's question.  Rarely does one SO user have deep insight into another user's question.  I was hoping for @K001 to explain the question more deeply, but if you know what @K001 knows, that's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably appropriate to centralise the logins, then add roles, and then link special properties for each group through a related table.

So yes, I'd assign roles, and keep login centralised (this means it can be one codebase to do the login, which is good).

Answer (score 2):

id use a roles based system as having 2 similar data structures may be a bad idea going forward - if you change one and not the other then you may have issues